# mod_rewrite in .htacess ignored after installing Let's Encrypt certificate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have two virtual hosts on a VPS running Ubuntu 18.04 and Apache 2.4.29.

I'll refer to them as "project" and "project2"

I installed an SSL certificate for "project" with LetsEncrypt.

**After doing so, I've found that it ignores all RewriteRules for that domain.** I entered a very simple RewriteRule (without a condition) to just redirect to example.com:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I've tried entering it into the host configuration file for "project", as well as into the .htaccess file. In both cases, it has no effect.

I've confirmed that the .htaccess file is being read, because if I deliberately put some garbage into it, I get a 500 error.

phpinfo() confirms that mod_rewrite is loaded, and if I run `a2enmod rewrite`, it returns a message that "Module rewrite already enabled."

I've confirmed that the behavior is confined only to the virtual host for the "project" domain. I have the exact same RewriteRule in the .htaccess file for the "project2" domain, and this RewriteRule is executed. The only difference seems to be that I have not installed an SSL certificate for the "project2" domain.

I've checked the Apache error logs and I can't find anything that shines any light on this.

**One other unexpected behavior that I think may be related is that I cannot navigate to http://project.com. It always forces me to https://project.com.** I can't find where this originates.

Below are the pertinent files for "project" with commented stuff removed for easier reading.

**project.conf** (/etc/apache2/sites-available/project.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@project.com
        ServerName project.com
        ServerAlias www.project.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/html/project/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**project-le-ssl.conf** (/etc/apache2/sites-available/project-le-ssl.conf)

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@project.com
        ServerName project.com
        ServerAlias www.project.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/project.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/project.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**apache2.conf** (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf)

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

**.htaccess** (/var/www/html/project/.htaccess) (the identical .htaccess file for "project2" is at /var/www/html/project2/.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

**options-ssl-apache.conf** (/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf)

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECD$
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Those are the only files I'm aware of that bear on the subject, though I imagine there are other that I'm not aware of.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is causing the RewriteRule for "project" to be ignored? And of secondary importance, does anyone know where the instructions are that won't allow me to navigate http://project.com after installing the SSL certificate?

Comment: I am not sure why, but you must change `SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` to `SSLProtocol             -all +TLSv1.2`. Allowing other protocols other than TLSv1.3 would result in a serious loss of security. Also, to check the force redirection, check the files like `ssl.conf`.

Comment: So, it wound up being pretty simple - for "project", I had Laravel installed, and my Laravel installation created an .htaccess file inside the `/var/html/project/public` folder. This one was being executed instead of the one I created in side the `/var/html/project` folder. My `project2` folder didn't have Laravel, so this .htaccess file was never created inside of it. The automatic redirect from http to https was something that Google Chrome was doing.